# Is it possible to render zero-width unicode characters as a special replacement character with a custom font?

Tags: windows, unicode, fonts

I'm trying to figure out a way to render certain unicode characters as a custom character instead of how they are supposed to appear.

For example, I would like the character U+0E4A to render as something else rather than how it currently appears in Windows.

I tried to create a quick custom font and to replace those glyphs but it only seems to work in some programs. My font will work correctly in LibreOffice Writer but it won't display properly in WordPad. Replacing regular letters works fine, but for other unicode characters they seem to revert back to a default way of rendering and don't display correctly.

Here is a screenshot of my custom font in WordPad, as you can see I made an obvious edit to the B character but I also did the same to the U+0E4A code point and yet it renders as normal.

[image: WordPad Screenshot]

If there is a special font that already does this that would probably save me the time of making a custom font, but either way I can't figure out how to render these characters as a custom character.

Comment: Why do you want a different glyph for U+0E4A in particular? What is it you're trying to do (besides see a different glyph)?

Comment: I play a video game in which some players use unicode spoofing to copy other players names. Certain characters like U+0E4A don't render in the game so if you use them in your name it can look identical to another player. Many of the characters they use are not used by any legit players so if I could use a custom font to replace these characters with any symbol it would make it much easier to identify the copy-cat.

Comment: But you've picked a combining mark for Thai script. Why that particular mark? Is the entire name using Thai-script characters? It would help to know what the entire string you're wanting to use is like.

Comment: Yeah, they just copy a persons name and then they add that character to the end or somewhere in the middle (e.g. Wilson\u0E4A) . They also use \u200f, \u202c and some other characters that don't display as anything in the name string. Normally if you have an identical name then the game will append a number to the end of your name so that you can be distinguished from the other player, but if you use one of these unusual characters then your name will appear identical and the other players will often get the two players confused.

Comment: How will changing the glyph for 0E4A from the default display in Windows benefit? "Wilson" and "Wilson๊" look different already, don't they?

Comment: Well in the game the thai character is invisible or cut off so both those strings would look identical. The other characters that I posted are also not supposed to display as anything, but I want them to. I effectively want a font that displays the majority of non-latin characters as some sort of error symbol rather than how they are meant to appear.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I think the challenge you're facing is that you, as a user of an app, can't control what font(s) the app uses to display text in its user interface. It will undoubtedly have some font it specifies for UI text. Depending on how the app's UI is implemented, there may be a "font fallback" mechanism that selects alternate fonts if the primary font doesn't support particular characters that are displayed in the UI. Users might be given options for the primary font, but it's not common; and it's extremely unlikely they'd be given any options for changing the fallback fonts.

Comment: You can use custom fonts in the game. I able to get my fonts working fine, but they have a fall back mechanism like you said. It seems that WordPad has a similar fall back, if a character is not included in a font it will use a replacement font to display the character. If I could get a font that displays the character but as an error character instead then I think it will work. Editing fonts is quite complex though, that's why I am asking the question here to see if anyone could point me in the right direction for making something like this.

Comment: That makes it sound like your question is how to build a font, but your opening question suggests you already know how to do that. Is it that you've created a custom glyph for 0E4A, but it's not displaying in Wordpad?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I can get the custom glyph to show in LibreOffice Writer but WordPad seems to handle things differently. In WordPad it appears as though certain unicode code points are replaced with a combination of glyphs by the font engine. The character U+0E4A seems to be replaced by a space and another character rather than just printing the glyph in the font file. Unfortunately I don't know how to find out what other glyphs are used in order to replace them and get the character to display how I want it.

Comment: WordPad is probably applying some heuristics to determine whether the font can actually support Thai script (0E3A is a Thai script mark), and determining that it needs to substitute a different font. But if your purpose is for use in a different app, does it matter whether it works in WordPad?

Comment: Well, the game uses windows apis at a low level. I think it makes calls to ExtTextOut(). It seems to have similar behaviour to WordPad so I was using that quickly for testing. I managed to get it working eventually. I think what was happening was that windows was detecting that I had only replaced one character of the Thai script and so it used a substitute font instead. When I replaced the majority of the characters with a dummy it seems to work as expected. The only problem is some characters are still substituted with the space character, but I think that's something I can't override.

Comment: Notepad uses the USER32 Edit control, which doesn't have much if any font-handling logic on top of GDI. WordPad uses the Windows RichEdit control, and has more font-handling logic. Testing in Notepad will get you closer to GDI APIs.